# Помогите настроить flake8 в PyCharm 2020.2

Tags: python, pycharm, flake8

Пытаюсь настроить flake8 на PyCharm. Прочитала много статей, но почему-то не работает.
Что делаю:
`File -> Settings -> External Tools`, жму на плюсик, добавляю новое, настройки на скрине.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В интернете пишут, что нужно искать файл с `flake8` в папке `venv\bin`, но у меня такого нет. С такими настройками показывает `Process finished with exit code 1`, но никакие ошибки не выводит.

Comment: Директория `venv` обычно для файлов virtual environment питона. Его можно создать во вкладке `Python Interpreter -> add -> Virtualenv Environment`

Comment: @dIm0n, таки `venv` есть, а `bin` нет

Comment: На винде это `Scripts`, так что вы правильно указали. Попробуйте запустить из `cmd`, чтобы увидеть более точную ошибку

Comment: @dIm0n, запустила из командной строки: прописала полный путь к `flake.exe`,  затем через пробел путь к файлу, который нужно было проверить `.py`. В командной строке выдался Fatal Error (хотя я кажется поняла, почему - в пути имеются русские буквы): `Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using flake8.exe filename.py filename.py: ?? ??????? ????? ????????? ????`

Answer (score 2):

Настройки на скрине - верные. Проблема заключалась в том, что пути до файлов `python.exe`, `flake8.exe` и `filename.py` содержали русские символы. Стоило их убрать и пересоздать проект - все заработало.